# Django One-To-Many Models

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-many

The following models describe a vulnerability and the URLs out on the internet that reference that vulnerability. Assume that each URL only ever talks about 1 vulnerability, and that many URLs will discuss that vulnerability. Is this the correct way to lay out the model?

```
class Vuln(models.Model):
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Publication Date")
  short_description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=70)

  reference_urls = models.ForeignKey(Url, unique=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Reference URLs")
  vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, verbose_name="Vendor")

class Url(models.Model):
  url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=200)
```

The Admin application gives a 'select' box for the reference URLs, which isn't what I want. When I add a new vulnerability object, all of the existing URLs that have been entered show up in that dropdown, which is again unnatural. I feel like this should behave very similar to how a blog comment would, ie. the comment applies to a single blog entry and none other and that one blog entry may have many comments. How do I express this in a Django model?

Comment: Also, as a matter of style, it would be better to use `Vulnerability` as a table name, rather than `Vuln` - it's longer, but at least you don't think "What the heck is a vuln" like I did when you see it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be more like this:

```
class Vuln(models.Model): 
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Publication Date") 
  short_description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=70)
  vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, verbose_name="Vendor") 

class Url(models.Model): 
  url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=200)
  vulnerability = models.ForeignKey(Vuln)
```

If you're saying each Url talks about a specific vulnerability, then there is your relation in the Django DBM :)

As for the vendor field, you simply add another class, much like Class Vuln. For example:

```
class Vendor(models.Model): 
  field_names_go_here = models.TextField(max_length=70)
  short_description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=70)
```

Hope this helps!
Regards, Alex